# Web development. Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Can someone please guide me through where am I going wrong in this piece of code below

index.php :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fun(){
    alert("H");
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'test.php',
    data: {name: 'Wayne', age: 27},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(error){
        alert(error);
    }
});
    alert("HE");
    }
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="fun()" />
```

test.php :-

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    echo $name.$age;
?>
```

I'm not getting any output nor any error.

Comment: In your PHP file, you can follow [this to show errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: When you say you don't get output, do you mean that not even the first `alert("H")` shows up? If so then the problem isn't with the the Ajax. I see no syntax errors in the JS shown.

Comment: @nnnnnn Um, the button is labeled as type="button"

Comment: @epascarello Um...I don't know what I was thinking. (Guess I saw the `value="submit"` and confused it.) I've edited my comment.

Comment: So do you have jQuery included since you are using it? If you open up the developer console is there any errors listed?

Comment: you have an input type = submit ... does that mean you have a form?

Comment: `I'm not getting any output nor any error` - really? nothing in the browsers developer tools console at all?

Comment: By no output nor any error, I meant for the ajax part. I'm getting the alert("H") as output. I kept these alert("H") and alert("HE") just to test whether my page gives a response or not. But alert("HE") is not displayed.

Comment: Cool people. I got the output. Actually, I didn't include jquery of which I was not aware of. Thanks for the help guys and keep helping ;)

Comment: I don't understand how you didn't get an error if you tried calling `$.ajax` but you hadn't included the jquery file. Had you looked in your browser console?

Comment: Even I am thinking of that. I checked my browser console but had no error there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the javascript code, specifically in how you're calling the function. Try this instead:

```
// javascript
document.getElementById('do-fun').addEventListener('click',function(){
    fun();
});

// html
<input type="button" value="submit" id="do-fun" />
```

Comment: I'm not so sure. I think there's something going on with the scope of the function causing it to not fire...

Comment: Adding the event listener like that wouldn't work with the provided document structure that has the script element *before* the input in question.